# How to verify just the first line in xpath //span/p using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I just want to verify the portion of the text given in the below code.

```
textPresent = driver.find_element_by_xpath ("//span/p")
```

is giving me the below

```
Successfuly added to execution processing!

{"Date":"5/13/2014","$$hashKey":"00F","memberId":"TOP","instrumentType":"MEE","S‌​ymbol":"IPL","quantity":"400","price":113.99}
```

So i can't really do

```
assert(textPresent == 'Successfully added to processing')
```

Comment: <div>
<div class="alertbox alert ng-scope alert-success" ng-class="type && "alert-" + type" close="closeAlert($index)" type="alert.type" ng-repeat="alert in alerts">
<button class="close" ng-click="close()" type="button" ng-show="closeable">×</button>
<div ng-transclude="">
<span class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-bind-html-unsafe="alert.msg">
<p>
Successfuly added to execution processing!
<br>
<br>
{"Date":"5/13/2014","$$hashKey":"00F","memberId":"TOP","instrumentType":"MEE","S‌​ymbol":"IPL","quantity":"400","price":113.99} 
</p>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate your text with `text()` function. Something like `//span/p[text()='Successfuly added to execution processing! ']` or you can use search with `contains()` function `//span/p[contains(text(),'Successfuly added to execution processing!')]`

Comment: I tried that, but its failing with the below error.   InvalidSelectorException: Message: u'The given selector //span/p[text(), \'Successfuly added to execution processing!\'] is either invalid or does not result in
 a WebElement. The following error occurred:\nInvalidSelectorError: Unable to lo
cate an element with the xpath expression //span/p[text(), \'Successfuly added t
o execution processing!\'] because of the following error:\n[Exception... "The e
xpression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxE
rror)"  location: "<unknown>"]' ; Stacktrace:

Comment: but when I try this, //span/p[contains(text(), 'Successfuly added to execution processing!')] I'm getting the entire text in the page, which is Successfuly added to execution processing!

{"Date":"5/13/2014","$$hashKey":"00F","memberId":"TOP","instrumentType":"MEE","S‌​ymbol":"IPL","quantity":"400","price":113.99}

Comment: Thats because you have white space after exclamation sign. I'll update answer.

Comment: I hear you.  I've been struggling with this as i'm a beginner. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I updated my answer. What is the problem you are experiencing now?

Comment: when I use the contains() I'm getting the following error.  I pasted the code above in my initial post.  The text exists, but its in three lines and there is blank line in between.  Is that what causing the issue?  NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//span/p[contains(text(), \'Successfuly added to execution processing
!\')]"}' ;

Comment: Successfuly added to execution processing!
---This is a blank line in between when I post this its disappering. 
{"Date":"5/16/2014","$$hashKey":"055","memberId":"TOP","instrumentType":"FDE", Symbol":"INC","quantity":"4","price":40.99}